# I need to be able to add new divs to this current cycle

Tags: jquery

I really suck at programming (less than a week of experience) and can't figure out how to make #stuff3 or any other div I might create enter the loop cycle. Also, can anyone show me how to make it slide to the left instead of fade in and out?

Help a noob out.

http://jsfiddle.net/vu4khc6a/1/

```
setInterval(function () {
    if ($('#stuff1').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#stuff2').fadeOut(500);
        $('#stuff3').fadeOut(500);
        $('#stuff1').delay(500).fadeIn(250);
    } else if ($('#stuff2').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#stuff1').fadeOut(500);
        $('#stuff3').fadeOut(500);
        $('#stuff2').delay(500).fadeIn(250);
    } else {
        $('#stuff1').fadeOut(500);
        $('#stuff2').fadeOut(500);
        $('#stuff3').delay(500).fadeIn(250);

    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "enter the loop cycle"?

Comment: I need them to cycle through the divs I have hidden, displaying one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not showing 3 is because when `stuff1` is showing, `stuff2` is `display: none`, and when `stuff2` is showing `stuff1` is `display: none`, so your `if` statements never get down to the  `else`.  You need to keep track of what step you're on using a variable. Something like:

```
var currentStuff = 2;
setInterval(function () {
    if (currentStuff == 1) {
        $('#stuff2').fadeOut(500);
        $('#stuff3').fadeOut(500);
        $('#stuff1').delay(500).fadeIn(250);
        currentStuff = 2;
    } else if (currentStuff == 2) {
        $('#stuff1').fadeOut(500);
        $('#stuff3').fadeOut(500);
        $('#stuff2').delay(500).fadeIn(250);
        currentStuff = 3;
    } else {
        $('#stuff1').fadeOut(500);
        $('#stuff2').fadeOut(500);
        $('#stuff3').delay(500).fadeIn(250);
        currentStuff = 1;
    }
}, 3000);
```

Since `stuff1` is showing initially, `currentStuff` is starts at 2 so when the interval runs it will hit the second `if` and show `stuff2`. It then increments `currentStuff` to 3 so `stuff3` shows on the next interval, and finally once `stuff3`is showing `currentStuff` rolls back over to 1 and `stuff1` will show.